# PostgreSQL 8.4 Win 32Bit, replication strategies to 64 bit Linux

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-8.4

So we have an application that uses PostgresSQL 8.4 on windows (yeah I know)..

We have several of these apps in our country.

What we want to do is have a linux server in a data centre, that stores a full copy of the database, and have the data stream into it fairly regularly.

This doesn't need to be real-time 100% consistent, but we want to get as close to that as possible as we will use to track sales data through the day.

The "slave" (data centre) doesn't need to do anything other then receive all the data, and then an app will run some reports on it.

I've looked into it, slony, pgpool, running 32 bit PostgreSQL on 64 bit linux etc but it's a big area so looking for some advise on our less then ideal setup.

Comment: Slony, Londiste or Bucardo, basically

Comment: Do these work in the 32 bit / 64 bit difference? Can I run 8.4 replicating to 9.x or do I need to keep versions the same?

Comment: Just give it a [try](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), create a small test setup.

Comment: I have tried Slony, I get error message, and I'm unsure as to what may cause it. Before I spend a lot of time trying to work it out, I want to know if there is a preferred way to do this stuff, as there is at least 8 rep technologies mentioned on the postgres site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic options are, as Craig pointed out, Bucardo, Londiste, and Slony.  These are all somewhat complex to set up compared to streaming replication.

The big thing you can't do is use the streaming replication or similar solutions.  These apply architecture (and major-version) -specific log files, and so going across architectures will on good days just not work and on bad days lead to data corruption on the slave.  Don't do it.

These three solutions pull the data out in an architecture-independent format and send it through an additional infrastructure to be saved on the slave.  There are big tradeoffs here and I would recommend thoroughly researching each option thoroughly before committing.

One thing to keep in mind is that the PostgreSQL community is typically quite adamant that there is no one-size-fits-all replication solution possible and so the multitude of options leads to many often solutions each of which is usually quite specialized.

Of these, Slony is probably the most configurable and Londiste is the simplest. They are for very different use cases though.  If i have time and nobody beats me to it, I may post a comparison of the three or at least link to others.

**Update**:  Brief comparison.

Slony-I

Slony-I is the the oldest and most powerful logical replication system available.  I actually prefer to think of Slony-I as a replication *toolkit* rather than a solution.  The toolkit approach offers incredible flexibility and the ability to solve all kinds of problems in complex environments.  The downside is that the flexibility is complexity.  As I put it, "Slony will happily let you replicate only part of your database.  On the other hand, Slony will happily let you replicate only part of your database."  It is an extremely helpful solution and makes all kinds of things possible, but the complexity is much higher than the other solutions.

One major advantage of Slony however is the fact that it has tools for managing DDL changes.  Londiste and Bucardo do not to my knowledge.  This means that adding columns to tables is possible on Slony but not so much on the other systems.

Bucardo

This is somewhere between Londiste and Slony in complexity.  It has the primary useful feature of being able to do multi-master replication between two masters.  It uses Perl extensively.  I don't know how well it has been tested on Windows, and this may be a drawback.

Londiste

Londiste is Skype's master-slave replication system built on pgq (basically an event queue connected to PostgreSQL with events raised on database actions).  It has a reputation of being easy to set up but not readily protecting replicas against modification.   this of course could be a feature or a bug depending on how you want to look at it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that. So does the streaming replication in 9.x care about architecture or it's ok? Any chance I could PM you about something?

Comment: It cares a lot about architecture.  Basically, unless you have the same on-disk layout, streaming replication can't work.  sure, feel free to pm me or email me if you can get my email from my profile.

Comment: Can't see your email there sorry? can you email me at brettskiii [at] gmail [dot] com